# weird behavior of merge() in @OneToMany relation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have simple relation between two entities

> One- Reservation -> Many- Seats

Entities are

```
@Entity
public class Reservation implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long reservationId;
    private String reservationDate;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reservation",  fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Seat> seats = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Seat>();
    // omitting get()s and set()s
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Seat implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long seatId;
    private Integer seatNumber;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "reservationId")
    private Reservation reservation;
     // omitting get()s and set()s
}
```

First I save reservation info then save seat info in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/proceed", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String checkOut(@ModelAttribute("passenger")Passenger passenger,
        @RequestParam("bus_id") String busId,
        @RequestParam("seats")List<Seat> seats) {

    passengerService.save(passenger);
    try {
        System.out.println("List size is " + seats.size());
        Bus selectedBus = busService.getById(Long.valueOf(busId));

        Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
        reservation.setBus(selectedBus);
        reservation.setPassenger(passenger);
        reservation.setReservationDate(new Date().toString());  
        // Saving reservation info here        
        reservationService.save(reservation);

        passenger.setReservation(reservation);
        passenger.setBus(selectedBus);
        passengerService.update(passenger);

        for (Seat seat : seats) {               
            seat.setBus(selectedBus);           
            seat.setReservation(reservation);// Here it gives weird results see details bellow 
            seatService.save(seat);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error is " + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Cause is " + e.getCause());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "reservation";
}
```

in following code

```
for (Seat seat : seats) {               
    seat.setBus(selectedBus);           
    seat.setReservation(reservation);
    seatService.save(seat);
}
```

SeatService save() is

```
@Override
public void save(Seat e) {
    entityManager.merge(e);
}
```

it saves `seats.size()` times more reservation objects in reservation table same info which were save before using `reservationService.save(reservation);`, I found the Line causing this result that is

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)// this line causes that weird behavior
@JoinColumn(name = "reservationId")
private Reservation reservation;
```

If I remove `cascade=CascadeType.ALL`, I get

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:
```

I also tried to change `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` to `cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST`, still getting same result(i.e it still saves `seats.size()` times more reservation objects in reservation table).

any solution to this please.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use merge for saving new entity.
From [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#merge(java.lang.Object)):

> Copy the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the same identifier. If there is no persistent instance currently associated with the session, it will be loaded. Return the persistent instance. **If the given instance is unsaved, save a copy of and return it as a newly persistent instance. The given instance does not become associated with the session.** This operation cascades to associated instances if the association is mapped with cascade="merge".

that means your instance `reservation` is not persistent and hibernate automatically inserts it each time on cascade.

Please try `entityManager.persist` instead or you have to make something like this:

ReservationService:

```
@Override
public Reservation save(Seat e) {
    return entityManager.merge(e);
}
```

and controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/proceed", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String checkOut(...) {
    ...
    Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
    ...
    reservation = reservationService.save(reservation);
    ...
}
```